# Need latest login record of user in user login report

Tags: php, mysql

Trying to generate user login report.

**login_history** table data:

```
id user_id login_date_time
1  2        2016-02-28 06:42:57
2  2        2016-02-29 06:42:57
3  2        2016-02-29 07:42:57
4  3        2016-02-28 06:42:57
5  3        2016-02-29 06:42:57
6  3        2016-02-29 08:42:50
7  4        2016-01-20 06:42:57
8  4        2016-02-29 06:42:57
9  4        2016-02-29 09:40:50
10 5        2016-02-28 05:42:56
```

**Login** table:

```
id username mobile
1  user1    1234567190
2  user2    1234567892
3  user3    2234567890
4  user4    1234567899
5  user5    1214567896
6  user6    1238567891
```

**Expected output:**

```
user2 2016-02-29 07:42:57
user3 2016-02-29 08:42:50
user4 2016-02-29 09:40:50
user5 2016-02-28 05:42:56
```

Need help regarding **MYSQL query.**

Comment: and what is your query ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple `INNER JOIN` with grouping can give you the required result set:

```sql
SELECT l.username, MAX(lh.login_date_time)
FROM Login AS l
INNER JOIN login_history AS lh
   ON l.id = lh.user_id
GROUP BY l.username
```

Comment: I think you forgot the group by:)

Answer (score 2):

So you need a join and group by clause:

```
SELECT t.username,max(s.login_date_time)
FROM Login t
INNER JOIN login_history s
 ON(s.user_id = t.id)
GROUP BY t.username
```